# Subdomain on WAMP Server Not Working

Tags: apache, virtualhost, wampserver

I'm having an important issue with my WAMP Server configuration. I've tried many configurations listed on many websites to no avail. I'm trying to make the directory /forums be accessible via https://forums.centmc.tk. However, upon travelling to https://forums.centmc.tk, it almost immediately says "forums.centmc.tk's server IP address could not be found." https://centmc.tk works fine, and so does the 301 redirect from https://centmc.tk/forums to https://forums.centmc.tk. I just can't figure out why the subdomain won't work.

I know it's an issue with my httpd-vhosts.conf file, so here's that:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost
DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot   c:/wamp64/www
ServerName     centmc.tk
SSLEngine      on
SSLCertificateFile c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/conf/centmc.tk.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/conf/centmc.tk.key
Redirect 301 /forums https://forums.centmc.tk
Redirect 301 /forum https://forums.centmc.tk
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName centmc.tk
ServerAlias forums.centmc.tk
VirtualDocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/forums"
ErrorLog "c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.27/logs/errors.log"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/forums">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for any help in advance! Sorry for the rather large text brick at the top.

Comment: Secure connections go in `httpd-ssl.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas.

Sounds like a DNS problem. If you are running a DNS server on your network, you will need to add an "A" record for the "forums" subdomain. Something like this:

```
; example.com [448369]
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA ns1.linode.com. admin.example.com. 2013062147 14400 14400 1209600 86400
@           MX  10  mail.example.com.
@           A   ###.###.###.###
mail        A   ###.###.###.###
www         A   <put your server IP here>
forums      A   <put your forums server IP here>
```

If you're using public DNS servers (like 8.8.8.8, 4.4.4.4, or just your default ISP's DNS servers... you'll need to add a CNAME record to wherever your domain name is registered. (GoDaddy for example). Here's a link to how to do it on GoDaddy: https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-subdomain-that-points-to-an-ip-address-4080

I hope that helps.

Comment: How would I go about this if they're both hosted on the same IP? Thanks! (Sorry for the noobish questions)

Comment: If they're both on the same IP, you would just put the same IP address in both the "www" A record and the "forums" A record. Then your Vhosts file should take care of the rest. (And no need to be sorry. We've all been there at some point!)